# Hadoop Avro file size concern

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, avro

I have a cronjob that that downloads zip files (200 bytes to 1MB) from a server on the internet every 5 minutes.  If I import the zip files into HDFS as is, I encounter the infamous Hadoop small file size issue.  In order to avoid the build up of small files in HDFS, process of the the text data in the zip files and convert them into avro files and wait every 6 hours to add my avro file into HDFS.  Using this method, I have managed to get avro files imported into HDFS with a file size larger than 64MB.  The files sizes range from 50MB to 400MB.  What I'm concerned about is that what happens if I start building file sizes that start getting into the 500KB avro file size range or larger.  Will this cause issues with Hadoop?  How does everyone else handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have some Hadoop post-aggregation step and that you're using some splittable compression type (sequence, snappy, none at all), you shouldn't face any issues from Hadoop's end.

If you would like your avro file sizes to be smaller, the easiest way to do this would be to make your aggregation window configurable and lower it when needed (6 hours => 3 hours?). Another way you might be able to ensure more uniformity in file sizes would be to keep a running count of lines seen from downloaded files and then combine upload after a certain line threshold has been reached.